# comparing files

Tags: unix

hi guys i have two pipe delimited files,first file contains 1000 records and second file contains 10 records and  records which are present in second file exists first file. Now need a file which which will give me 990 records by excluding 10 records which occur in both files,

i know how to this using SQL .But how can we acheive this in UNIX?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the files are `all` and `some`. Then do

```
 fgrep -v -f some all
```

Answer (score 1):

see the [join](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/join/) command

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it will work as inner join....i am looking for left outer join  in UNIX

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the pipes with newlines so we can process the files with line-oriented Unix tools. Then use `comm` to filter out the lines that appear in both files. Finally, convert the newlines back to pipes.

```
tr '|' '\n' < file1 | sort > file1.sorted
tr '|' '\n' < file2 | sort > file2.sorted
comm -3 file1.sorted file2.sorted | tr '\n' '|'
```

Or done all on one line using process substitution `<(command)` syntax:

```
comm -3 <(tr '|' '\n' < file1 | sort) <(tr '|' '\n' < file2 | sort) | tr '\n' '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [comm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm) utility can be used to filter lines from one file out of another

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$0++;next}(!($0 in a))' some all
```